# Which AI branch should I follow?

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence

I'm doing some testings on NLP and I was thinking to write a code that works like this.

Subject -> User input -> Output

Dog ownership -> I own a dog -> Yes

Dog ownership -> My dog is called Joe -> Yes

Dog ownership -> I don't have a dog -> No

Which branch or ai algorithm do you think that would be the best approach for this problem?

I'm not expecting someone to solve my problem, just to point me in the right direction.
Thanks!!

Comment: Are you aware that there are other sister [sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#science-questionsperday) to SO where more of the experts in NLP would hang out than here?

Comment: I wasn't, no I am. Anyway, NLP experts might also be here since this is the largest community in Stack Exchange. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that what you want is a [dialog system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialog_system). If you restrict the user input to yes/no questions then that will keep your project relatively simple. The way I would go about this is to create a chatbot using AIML and Python. Here is [an example](http://www.devdungeon.com/content/ai-chat-bot-python-aiml).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with NLP, but your samples could easily be done using AIML pattern matching (AIML is a distant descendent of [Eliza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELIZA)). For example:

```
<category> <!-- 1 -->
  <pattern>I OWN A DOG</pattern>
  <template>
    <think><set name="dog_owner">true</set></think>
    You own a dog.
  </template>
</category>

<category> <!-- 2 -->
  <pattern>I DO NOT OWN A DOG</pattern>
  <template>
    <think>
      <set name="dog_owner">false</set>
      <set name="dog_name"></set>
    </think>
    You do not own a dog.
  </template>
</category>

<category> <!-- 3 -->
  <pattern>DO I OWN A DOG</pattern>
  <template>
    <condition name="dog_owner">
      <li value="true">You own a dog.</li>
      <li>You don't have a dog.</li>
    </condition>
  </template>
</category>

<category> <!-- 4 -->
  <pattern>MY DOG IS CALLED *</pattern>
  <template>
    <think>
      <set name="dog_owner">true</set>
      <set name="dog_name"><star/></set>
    </think>
    Your dog is called <get name="dog_name"/>.
  </template>
</category>
```

Categories 1 and 2 allow you to tell the AIML intepreter whether you have a dog, it stores this fact (and the dog's name) in properties "dog_owner" and "dog_name". Category 3 gives the correct answer when you ask if you have a dog, and 4 allows you to choose the dog's name. These categories could be extended to allow the dog's name to be forgotten, or to allow cats etc. Hopefully this shows you AIML's NLP support, so you can decide if it's useful.